# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error when i try to access the server running on localhost on laptop from my mobile devise connected to same wifi network

Tags: node.js, networking, wifi, ip-address

I want to access the server that I have build using node.js from my android phone. My server is running on localhost port 80 and my laptop and mobile device is connected to the same wifi network.
I tried turning off the windows defender firewall but it didn't work.
In my mobile device browser, I used the link to make a request to my server as

```
laptop_ip_address:port_no/home
```

But it didn't work.
I get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in my browser.
I don't want to use ngrok.
what should I do?
this is my server code
const express=require("express")

```
const app=express()
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send("<h1>hiiii</h1><a href='/home'>hii</a>")
    
}) 
app.get("/home",(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send("<h1>yooo</h1>")
}) 

app.listen(80,()=>{
    console.log("App is running");
})
```

Comment: Localhost is the loopback address, and it cannot be used on the network outside the host. Anything sent to localhost immediately loops back inside the host. You need to run your server on an interface connected to the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try after adding cors module. This may help to solve the issue.

```
const cors=require('cors')
const app=express()

app.use(cors);

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send("<h1>hiiii</h1><a href='/home'>hii</a>")
    
}) 
app.get("/home",(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send("<h1>yooo</h1>")
}) 

app.listen(80,()=>{
    console.log("App is running");
})
```